# Insert space in string using powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a number of files, each with a number of lines of plain text in them and I'd like to insert a space between certain "words".

I have no problem looping the files, or replacing some text with different text, but not sure how to keep the existing text when I do so!

```
$ln = "20142301 Starting_LOC1SVR14"
$newln = $ln -replace "_", " "
$newln = $newln -replace "LOC[0-9]","????"
```

Given this sample, I want to insert the space between `LOC1` and `SVR14` to give `LOC1 SVR14`

Note that the LOC goes up to 16, but I can write the regex for 1 or more numerals, it's keeping that `LOC1` part thats giving me the headache!

Comment: Sorry, gave me `20142301 Starting_\0 SVR14`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up regexp [capture groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They are used to save the matching string into a variable that can be used later like so,

```
$newln -replace "LOC[0-9]+","$0 " # $0 is the match, so replace the match with "match "
20142301 Starting LOC1 SVR14
```